# Does a pativrata stree take the husband to heaven even if the husband did sins in his life?

Tags: marriage, heaven, wife

Does a pativrata stree take the husband to heaven even if the husband did sins in his life ? Is it true that even if someone is sinner but his wife is patrivrata , he because of his wife goes to heaven.

Comment: I’m obsessed w/ Hindu-mytho stories and there are many horrid guys who basically stayed ok despite huge sins cause of their wife’s virtue and astha (auto correct keeps changing that to asthma. I mean “astha” like faith.) Like Mandodari getting amrit from moon for Ravan navel which kept him propped up so long and the Narayan-bhakt  lady who became Tulsi-devi married to the asur who wouldn’t stop behaving horribly and things like that. Not heaven entrance perhaps but def hanging in there due to pativrat wife. Someone with proper citations and things will hopefully give proper answer to your ques

Comment: @devibhakt Yeah Husband of a true pativrata lady [can't die before her death.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51237/23709) . i just wanted to know if they go heaven as well. I suspect it is true.